Dependency injection approach for object used only in a single method
I'm migrating an old ASP.NET 4.7.2 MVC application to ASP.NET Core and wish to learn more of the DI approach, since it's already deeply integrated into the Core framework. However, so far I've encountered some issues utilizing it. I understand DI is supposed to be used across the call chain, with every class having its dependencies injected. But what if you want to use an instance of a class only in a specific method of your current one? Are you supposed to inject it for the whole class, wasting performance on potentially heavy instantiations when it's not necessary?
Here's an example;
public class TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger)
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do work here
    }

    public void DoAnotherThing()
    {
        // Do work here
    }

    private void CallSomethingFromInnerClass()
    {
        // Problematic code
        new InnerClass().DoInnerClassWork();
    }
}

public class InnerClass(ILogger<InnerClass> logger)
{
    public void DoInnerClassWork()
    {
        // Do work here
    }
}

I have a class that has many methods, each doing its own thing. Assume that class cannot be split into different smaller classes, maybe it's a controller. The inner class expects a logger with its own category. Now, I could instantiate it in the method and pass the existing logger, but that logger would have the wrong category (TestClass instead of InnerClass). I could also inject an IServiceProvider, however as I understand that is an anti-pattern and shouldn't be done when implementing DI.  I could also introduce a [FromService] attribute, however that is also an anti-pattern, plus it only works for controller actions called from the environment, not private methods.
Another approach would be to indeed separate the method to a different object (see this). However, doesn't that just kick the can down the road? If you would need to then inject that object to call the method, doesn't the injection still happen for the whole TestClass?
What is the best approach here? Is the answer really injecting it for the whole class? What if the inner class is an ORM helper, do I need to create a DB connection every time?

When migrating to ASP.NET Core, adopting dependency injection (DI) for objects used in specific methods balances efficiency and maintainability. Injecting dependencies for the entire class aligns with SOLID principles, enabling easier testing and code consistency. Techniques like lazy initialization or factory methods optimize performance by deferring object creation until needed. Separating concerns into smaller classes when methods require distinct dependencies enhances code clarity.

I'd say it is mostly a preference. Some people use MediatR for controllers to keep constructor parameter length low. Some people separate controllers in a more granular way (minimal apis, fastendpoint). I'd say that ORM helper should not create connection in constructor rather in each method or on the first method usage

Regarding best practice, typically involves injecting dependencies for the whole class, even if the dependency is used in a single method. This promotes consistency, testability, and adheres to SOLID principles.

Lazy initialization is used in this kind of situations and it can be applied on DI aswell. See => link

@MdFaridUddinKiron I agree it would be the most consistent approach, however it's not always an option. I gave a simplified example, which mixes up the controller with business logic much lower in the actual application. The InnerClass simply cannot be afforded to instantiate every time.

@YBB This seems like a fantastic solution to the problem. I'd have to test it of course, as well as read up on the potential drawbacks of it and if it's considered an anti-pattern, but this seems like what IEnumerable<T> is for collections and LINQ. Please post this as an answer to the question so I can mark it as a solution. Also, @MdFaridUddinKiron what do you think of this?

To be honest, I don't bindly follow anything before unless I got the concreate requirement.  You generally do not need to create a new DB connection every time due to connection pooling. Instead, inject a service like DbContext (for Entity Framework Core) throughout your application where needed. So, you can use lazy initialization to create the instance only when it is first accessed. Thus, its a programmer's call depending on scenario and I mostly focused on implementation oriented problem in stackoverflow not opinion centric issues as it varies all the time.

Its hard to explain all the stuff in comment, so I need to prepare an answer to exaplain those.

Lazy initialization is used in this kind of situations and it can be applied on DI aswell see => Lazy initialization

Update: the provided source has some seemingly outdated information. For reference, I used builder.Services.AddScoped<InnerClass>(); and then builder.Services.AddScoped<Lazy<InnerClass>>(provider => new Lazy<InnerClass>(provider.GetRequiredService<InnerClass>)), without calling builder.Services.AddAppDependencies(); because it's no longer a part of any assembly I found. After that, everything is as the article says.


What if you want to use an instance of a class only in a specific
method of your current one? Are you supposed to inject it for the
whole class, wasting performance on potentially heavy instantiations
when it's not necessary?

According to your scenario, If you want to use an instance of a class only in a specific method, you don't necessarily need to inject it for the entire class.
While injecting dependencies for the entire class is the most straightforward and maintainable approach, using factory methods, lazy initialization, or method-level injection can provide performance benefits without violating DI principle.
Both has pros and corns actually. So, as I told you earlier, its a programmer's call or preference.

If you would need to then inject that object to call the method,
doesn't the injection still happen for the whole TestClass?

When injecting a dependency into a class in ASP.NET Core, the injection happens at the class level, meaning the dependency is available to all methods within that class. However, this does not necessarily mean that the dependency is instantiated immediately or that it has a heavy performance impact.

What is the best approach here? Is the answer really injecting it for
the whole class? What if the inner class is an ORM helper, do I need
to create a DB connection every time?

As it has couple of approach you could decide depending on which one actually best fits within your scenario.
If you prefer, Lazy initialization, it defers the creation of the instance until it is first accessed. In that scenario, you can do something like below:
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestClass> _logger;
    private readonly Lazy<InnerClass> _innerClass;

    public TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _innerClass = new Lazy<InnerClass>(() =>
            new InnerClass(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<InnerClass>>()));
    }

    private void CallSomethingFromInnerClass()
    {
        _innerClass.Value.DoInnerClassWork();
    }
}

In addition, For ORM helpers like DbContext, Entity Framework Core manages connections efficiently through connection pooling. Injecting DbContext into your services is typically efficient because it does not create a new database connection each time but reuses existing connections from the pool.
Yeah one thing is obvious, lazy initialization, or scoped/transient services can provide a balance between efficiency and adherence to dependency injection principles.
Note: If you have time, I would recommned you to check this official document.

Your answer is thorough and does indeed solve the issue. I'm accepting @YBB's answer since he mentioned lazy injection first, but after playing with the solution for a bit this seems like a good solution, the only change being setting up the instance provider in the Main method instead. Thank you for your effort and time :)

P.S. I had the impression that method-level injection using IServiceProvider or [FromService] in controller actions were considered anti-patterns and are no-nos. Would you agree, or how do you see them?

Its absolutely alright, I just tried to assist you, have fun man.

Using IServiceProvider or [FromServices] might seem convenient, but again its preference man.


But what if you want to use an instance of a class only in a specific method of your current one? Are you supposed to inject it for the whole class, wasting performance on potentially heavy instantiations when it's not necessary?

Injection constructors should be simple and any heavy initialization should be postponed until after the object graph has been created. This make the construction of big object graphs very lightweight and fast, in which case you typically don't have to worry about wasting performance.
Postponing initialization means, for instance, not connecting to the database inside the constructor, but instead when the class is first used. O/RMs like Entity Framework, for instance, use this approach. Only when any of the DbSet properties are called, will connections to the database be made. Injecting an unused DbContext is fairly lightweight.
Still, object graphs consisting of thousands of instances could still cause performance problems. My experience, however, is that very large object graphs only exist with object graphs where its classes apply the Constructor Over-Injection code smell. In other words, classes that violate the Single Responsibility Principle.
And besides reducing the number of dependencies a class has, a typically quicker fix (or workaround) is to increase the lifetime of dependencies. For instance from Transient to Scoped. This caches the component with all its created dependencies and can severely reduce the number of created objects in the object graph.

I have a class that has many methods, each doing its own thing.

If methods have a low cohesion, this is an indication of a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Assume that class cannot be split into different smaller classes, maybe it's a controller.

Even controllers can be split up into, and arguably should be when their number of constructor arguments grows. Some care must be taken, though, to ensure the application's API URL paths should stay the same to prevent breaking clients.
